# Resource not found in PowerApps when connecting to API?

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-functions, powerapps

I am trying to send some images to power app using a custom connector.

My OpenAPI file looks this -

```
{
"swagger": "2.0",
"info": {
"version": "1.0.0",
"title": "Upload To Function"
},
"host": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX/.azurewebsites.net",
"paths": {
"/api/HttpTriggerCSharp/name/{name}": {
  "post": {
    "tags": [
      "HttpTriggerCSharp"
    ],
    "operationId": "UploadImage",
    "consumes": [
      "multipart/form-data"
    ],
    "produces": [
      "application/json",
      "text/json",
      "application/xml",
      "text/xml"
    ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "file",
        "in": "formData",
        "required": true,
        "type": "file",
        "x-ms-media-kind": "image"
      },
      {
        "name": "name",
        "in": "path",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Saved successfully"
      },
      "400": {
        "description": "Could not find file to upload"
      }
    },
    "summary": "Image Upload",
    "description": "Image Upload"
  }
  }
 },
 "definitions": {}
}
```

My function works as I have tested it out using POSTMAN, and also within the Azure function portal. But when I test it out on Powerapps using this swagger file, I get Status code 404, Resource not found error.

I call my function like this in Powerapps -

```
Uploadtofunction.uploadimage(MainimageView.image,{filename:"test")
```

Any idea, on why it's not working?

Edit: Here is how I tested it out on POSTMAN. I think its also related to the filename in swagger. Because when I add name/filename in the body, I get 500 internal server issue.

[image]

Comment: When you tested in Postman did you test with right path? Also your PowerApp expression looks a little off. You have a {filename which I assume may be a typo, and I also don’t see a place where you define the “name” path parameter — name : “SomeName”

Comment: @jeffhollan Can you please check edit. Thanks. 'Filename' parameter came up on the Powerapps when I added the connector, so I added that in.

Comment: I think the confusion is that multipart formdata often has a filename as part of the part in the content disposition headers. So you are providing a filename for the body, but you also have a path parameter called “name” I don’t see you setting. I would either remove potentially redundant name path parameter or change the body from in formdata and do type string format binary